# Need help to create a formula for a game

Tags: calculus

I am currently creating a game. In this game, you can upgrade buildings to another level by using resources (such as iron, platinum, etc).

Anyway, I am stuck trying to create a formula for the price based on the level of the building.

I have access to theses variables:

- Default price for the level 1 (ex: 175)
- The level of the building

I want to create a formula who's always like that:

- Level 2 = 175*2 = 350
- Level 3 = 350*2 = 700
- Level 4 = 700*2 = 1400
- etc..

Is that possible ? If so, how ?

No worries about how complicated it can be... If it work, it work.

Thanks for any help - been stuck for hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\text{Price of level $n$ = (Default price for level $1$)$ \times 2^{n-1}$.}$$
Hence, if default price for level $1$ is say $175$, then
$$\text{Price of level $n = 175 \times 2^{n-1}$.}$$

Answer (score 2):

***Price of level $n$=$175(2^{n-1})$***